# Make Windows32 API members expand to A, or Change Character set in vs2019 (c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

My problem is as follows. When I pass in strings into the methods/classes of the win32 api, I get the Problem, that the type "const char*" cannot be used to assign variables of type LPCWSTR. I than made a helper method, that converts const char* manually to LPCWSTR. In the most cases, this did the trick, but In the CreateWindow() function the same error remains.
I then read online, that to easily avoid this problem, one could change the Character set to UTF-8, but soon found out that vs2019 does not have this setting, where it was 2017.
What I want to know, basically, is whether there is a way change the character set in vs2019, or a way to manually force those Methods to expand to the A type instead of W by default (CreateWindow should automatically expand to CreateWindowA, instead of expanding to CreateWindowW).

Comment: You should be using unicode. It's 2020 not 1990.

Comment: Depends on your [`UNICODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes) setting.  Sounds like you don't want it set, but you do want UTF-8.  Probably won't work out very well.

Comment: Interesting that you think the solution is to use ANSI APIs and not just to use Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateWindow` expands to `CreateWindowW` if `UNICODE` is defined during compiling, otherwise it expands to `CreateWindowA`. Same with `TCHAR` (`wchar_t`/`char`, respectively) and all other `W`/`A`-based APIs.

So, either set the project's character set to ANSI/MBCS, or you can simply `#undef UNICODE` where needed.  Prior to Windows 10 version 1903 (build 18362), the `A` APIs simply do not support UTF-8 at all. But since then, you can opt in to enable UTF-8 support via the application manifest.

That being said, you should not rely on the `TCHAR`-based APIs if your string data is not using `TCHAR` to begin with.

If you are working with `char` data specifically, use the `A` APIs directly (`CreateWindowA`, etc), unless your data is UTF-8 (or different than the user's locale), in which case convert it to UTF-16 using `MultiByteToWideChar` or equivalent and then call the `W` APIs directly.

If you are working with `wchar_t` data specifically, use the `W` APIs directly (`CreateWindowW`, etc).